# Union two geometries from the same table, in the same table, keeping information of only one record

Tags: postgis

I have a table with several records. I want to union the geometries of two of the records, preserving the information from the other columns from only one record.

```
id   col1 col2 col3 geom
1    A    AA   123  Z
2    B    BB   456  X
NULL D    NULL NULL W
3    C    CC   789  V
```

Now I want to union the geometry of record `col1 = D` with `col1 = B`, preserving the information from the record with `col1 = B` in the newly created geometry.

```
id   col1 col2 col3 geom
1    A    AA   123  Z
2    B    BB   456  XW
3    C    CC   789  V
```

Bonus: Delete the old record in the same query.

Comment: By definition, relational tables are ***unordered***. Your problem statement doesn't provide any way to associate the NULL id record with any one feature.

Comment: Can you express in SQL? You using `t as t1 CROSS JOIN  t as t2`?  You need somethong as  `ST_UNION(t1.geom,t2.geom)   WHERE t1.col1='D' AND t2.col1='B'`?  Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the record you want to keep, rather than creating a new record:

```
update yourtable c set geom = d.geom from
(select a.id, st_union(a.geom, b.geom) as geom
from
yourtable as a,
yourtable as b
where a.col1 = 'B' and b.col1 = 'D') d
where c.id = d.id;

delete from yourtable where col1 = 'D';
```